# Every URL Displays Homepage

Tags: .htaccess

I'm migrating a site from Media Temple (GS) to (DV), but every URL without `index.php` returns the homepage. URLs *with* `index.php` display correctly.

FastCGI is disabled, here are the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/my/password.file
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthType Basic

require valid-user

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

EE 2.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally I've found this to be the URI_PROTOCOL config setting.

Go through the range of options in config.php and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your server requires the ? to make anything that follows index.php a querystring, it's probably not necessary in your RewriteRule and could lead to the behavior you're describing.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```